# Onclick recpective div open close exsting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a set of open and close div. please check below

if I click any link it will open the respective div but if any div is open previously it will close and open the current div clicked. If I hit same it will close.

```css
.content{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="maindiv">
<div class="content link1">Div link 1</div>
<div class="content link2">Div link 2</div>
<div class="content link3">Div link 3</div>
<div class="content link4">Div link 4</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: So you didn't try anything yet?

Comment: try javascript code,then ask

Comment: Try using jquery toggle/(hide/ show). Complete your homework before asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code snippet

```js
$('li a').on('click', hideShow);

function hideShow() {
  if($('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).hasClass('content')) {
    $('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase())[0].classList.remove('content');
  } else {
    $('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase())[0].classList.add('content');
  }
}
```

```css
.content{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="maindiv">
<div class="content link1">Div link 1</div>
<div class="content link2">Div link 2</div>
<div class="content link3">Div link 3</div>
<div class="content link4">Div link 4</div> 
</div>
```

Update as per your requirement:

```js
$('li a').on('click', hideShow);

function hideShow() {
  if($('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).hasClass('content')) {
  $('.maindiv > div').addClass('content');
    $('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).removeClass('content');
  } else {
    $('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).addClass('content');
  }
}
```

```css
.content{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="maindiv">
<div class="content link1">Div link 1</div>
<div class="content link2">Div link 2</div>
<div class="content link3">Div link 3</div>
<div class="content link4">Div link 4</div> 
</div>
```

you can animate background of div like below

```js
$('li a').on('click', hideShow);

function hideShow() {
  if($('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).hasClass('content')) {
  $('.maindiv > div').addClass('content');
    $('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).removeClass('content');
  } else {
    $('.'+this.textContent.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase()).addClass('content');
  }
}
```

```css
.content{
display:none;
}

.divs{
background-color: lavender;
-webkit-animation: slide 1s ease 3.5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {height: 0;}
to {height: 300px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="maindiv">
<div class="content divs  link1">Div link 1</div>
<div class="content divs link2">Div link 2</div>
<div class="content divs link3">Div link 3</div>
<div class="content divs link4">Div link 4</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, Thanks, it is very good and wery much working, but if i need only one div visible at a time then what to do? thanks in advance.

Comment: Its been my pleasure

Comment: one last query, can we give time or some slow/smooth effect into it.

Comment: you can provide effect on background. see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. It's working.

```js
$("div").each(function(){
     $(this).hide();
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'main') {
        $(this).show();
    }
});


$('a').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-related'); 
    $("div").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        if($(this).attr('id') == id) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="active" data-related="main">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-related="title_1">Title 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-related="title_2">Title 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-related="title_3">Title 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-related="title_4">Title 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="main">... Content ...</div>
<div id="title_1">... 1234 ...</div>
<div id="title_2">... 4567 ...</div>
<div id="title_3">... 8965 ...</div>
<div id="title_4">... 3434 ...</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ahmed, It is great. but can you help me little more. I need default all content div hide. on click it will open respective div. if i hit same again i will close.

Comment: @omkarsahu this doesnpt make sense. You mean the corresponding click should close it if open and open it if close ? :)

Comment: @bipen it is like tab, but i want to put my button some where else.

Comment: @omkarsahu, Please refer this link: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/  This might be useful in your case.